Actualizar un campo text desde una tabla remota
Tengo un sistema que guarda la firma electrónica capturada desde un PAD, en un campo de tipo text llamado firma.
Debo actualizar ese campo en la base de datos central a partir del dato guardado en la base de datos remota, y había hecho este query utilizando Linked Server
Declare @FecIni varchar(8)

set @FecIni = '20241215'

update bBDatos2 
SET firma = bRemota.firma
from bascula.dbo.Boletas  bBDatos2
inner join LS_GUADALUPE.bascula.dbo.Boletas bRemota 
    on bBDatos2.Boleta = bRemota.Boleta and bBDatos2.Base = bRemota.Base
WHERE bBDatos2.Base = 3 
AND bBDatos2.Fecha = @FecIni

Pero me está marcando el error:
No se pueden comparar ni ordenar los tipos de datos text, ntext e image, excepto cuando se utiliza el operador IS NULL o LIKE.
así que me entero que este tipo de datos no se comportan igual que los "normales", pero nunca había usado estos, es un sistema que heredé y que tiene, no sé, más de 15 años funcionando así, ¿alguien me podría orientar sobre cómo podría actualizar este campo con el valor que tiene el registro en la base de datos remota?

¿Intentaste castear los datos?

muchas gracias por tu sugerencia padaleiana lo voy a intentar

Los tipos de dato text y ntext son obsoletos y siempre ha sido problemático trabajar con ellos. Se recomienda reemplazar su uso con varchar(max) y nvarchar(max).
En tu caso, como es un sistema heredado y probablemente no puedas hacer el cambio completo por ahora, lo que necesitas es convertir el tipo de dato para poder utilizarlo.
Cada vez que tengas una columna text tienes que usar CAST o CONVERT para convertirlo en varchar(max).
También es importante que estés consciente de que hacer consultas que combinen datos entre tablas locales y tablas de servidores remotos van a tener problemas de rendimiento.

gracias, es lo que he estado leyendo, a la brevedad posible, haré el cambio en la base de datos, por lo pronto para mi requerimiento inmediato, haré el traspaso utilizando el varchar(max), ya hice pruebas y me funcionó bien
